# Lost connection to emulator error

Tags: bada, samsung-mobile

I have jut started with my bada app development and am stuck on the helloworld program because my emulator does not execute I get the following error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3C57.jpg)

Please help.

Comment: Start with some samples. Can they run? To place a sample into your workspace, use menu/window/Show View/Other, select "bada SDK samples", right-click one, select "Copy into my workspace".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped me:

Right-click on your project, select `Properties`, open `badaBuild` row and click.